Hangfire job is not scheduling
see this snapshot
please find some solution
var auto = new AutoCallService(dbContext, Configuration, _emailService, _mapper, _hostingEnvironment, _stripeApisService, _logService);

//var autoCallService = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IAutoCallService>();

//RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate( () => auto.TestJob(), "*/1 * * * *" );
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => auto.SendInvoiceToUser(), Cron.Hourly);
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("automatic-change-of-fighters-fighter-class-based-on-fighters-birthday", () => auto.UpdateFightClassForUser(), Cron.MinuteInterval(5),TimeZoneInfo.Utc);

Here is my hangfire configuration
services.AddHangfire(x => x.UseSqlServerStorage(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MSSQL"))
);

 app.UseHangfireDashboard("/hangfire", new DashboardOptions
 { 
Authorization = new List<IDashboardAuthorizationFilter>
 {
 new MyAuthorizationFilter() 
} 
});
 app.UseHangfireServer();


Show us the code you have to initialise and configure Hangfire?

Don't add code in comments, instead [edit] your question.

@DavidG please provide me any solution if you have
